# CAPL - Separate a string by commas and set in a matrix

Tags: arrays, string, capl

I have a string I got from a text file and I want to separate it from commas, and set each item in an array. I have a general idea on how to code this, but I want to make sure there is not any easier way do this. 
Is there a function to do this? I want something similar to split() in python, to use in a CAPL.

Before

```
char dataString[200] = "MAX_VOLT,  MAX_CURR,  MAX_TIME,  TEMP,  A0_MAX";
```

After

```
char dataArray[5][50] = {"MAX_VOLT","MAX_CURR","MAX_TIME","TEMP","A0_MAX"};
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a minimal CAPL script to test my idea:

```
variables {
  char dataString[200] = "MAX_VOLT,  MAX_CURR,  MAX_TIME,  TEMP,  A0_MAX";
  long pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5;
  char dataArray[5][50];
}

on start {
  int i;

  pos1 = strstr(dataString, ",");
  pos2 = strstr_off(dataString, pos1+1, ",");
  pos3 = strstr_off(dataString, pos2+1, ",");
  pos4 = strstr_off(dataString, pos3+1, ",");
  pos5 = strlen(dataString);
  write("pos1 = %d, pos2 = %d, pos3 = %d, pos4 = %d, pos5 = %d", pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, strlen(dataString));

  // get first string 
  for (i = 0; i < pos1; i++) {
    dataArray[0][i] = dataString[i];
  }
  // get second string 
  for (i = 0 ; i < pos2 - pos1 - 3; i++) {
    dataArray[1][i] = dataString[i + pos1 + 3];
  }
  // get third string 
  for (i = 0 ; i < pos3 - pos2 - 3; i++) {
    dataArray[2][i] = dataString[i + pos2 + 3];
  }
  // get fourth string 
  for (i = 0 ; i < pos4 - pos3 - 3; i++) {
    dataArray[3][i] = dataString[i + pos3 + 3];
  }
  // get fifth string 
  for (i = 0 ; i < pos5 - pos4 - 3; i++) {
    dataArray[4][i] = dataString[i + pos4 + 3];
  }

  write("%s", dataArray[0]);
  write("%s", dataArray[1]);
  write("%s", dataArray[2]);
  write("%s", dataArray[3]);
  write("%s", dataArray[4]);
}
```

output:

```
CAPL    pos1 = 8, pos2 = 19, pos3 = 30, pos4 = 37, pos5 = 46
CAPL    MAX_VOLT
CAPL    MAX_CURR
CAPL    MAX_TIME
CAPL    TEMP
CAPL    A0_MAX
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, which I did'nt test. First i would get the positions of all the commas in your `dataString[200]`. Use the function `strstr(char s1[], char s2[]);` to get the position of your first comma in `dataString`. Use the first comma position as an input parameter `offset` to get the following comma positions using the `strstr_off(char s1[], long offset, char s2[]);`. Same for remaining commas.

Then i would use for loops using the comma positions to copy the chars from `dataString` to `dataArray`. If you use the same `dataArray` within your CAPL script, make sure to empty the strings in `dataArray` when dealing with strings of different lengths and refilling `dataArray` with new strings. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A function doesn't seem to exist to easily split a string in CAPL similar to Python. I wrote this to achieve something similar.

```
variables
{
  char dataString[200] = "MAX_VOLT,MAX_CURR,MAX_TIME,TEMP,A0_MAX";
  char dataArray[10][50];
}

on start
{
  split_string(dataString, ",");
  write("%s", dataArray[0]);
  write("%s", dataArray[1]);
  write("%s", dataArray[2]);
  write("%s", dataArray[3]);
  write("%s", dataArray[4]);
}

int split_string(char string[], char delim[])
{
  int start_pos, end_pos;
  int i, j;
  int num_strings;
  
  start_pos = 0;
  end_pos = 0;
  num_strings = 0;
  
  while (start_pos < strlen(string))
  {
    j = 0;
    end_pos = strstr_off(string, start_pos, delim);
    if (end_pos == -1)
    {
      end_pos = strlen(string);
    }
    for (i=start_pos; i<end_pos; i++)
    {
      dataArray[num_strings][j++] = string[i];
    }
    dataArray[num_strings][j] = '\0';
    num_strings++;
    start_pos = end_pos+strlen(delim);
  }
  
  return num_strings;
}
```

It doesn't remove spaces but that can probably easily be added by using str_replace.